# How to change UIbuttons textcolors when we tapped on it in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

In ios in my ViewController I have added four buttons and their related indicators OK

When I tap on button4 then button4 and it's indicator color must be black color and all the other all buttons and their indicators colors must be white.  When I click button2 then button2 the textcolor and indicator must be black.  The  remaining buttons textcolors and indicators must be white as like below image

For this I have written some code but it's not working.

Please can you help me

### my code:-

```
#import "ViewController12.h"
#import "Masonry.h"

@interface ViewController12 ()
{
    UIView * TabBar;
    UIButton * AllTrips;
    UIButton * OpenTrips;
    UIButton * AssignedTrips;
    UIButton * CompletedTrips;
    UIButton * button;
    UIView * StripView;
    UILabel * label;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController12

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    TabBar = [[UIView alloc]init];
    TabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    TabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:TabBar];

    [TabBar mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.top.equalTo(@0);
        make.left.equalTo(@0);
        make.right.equalTo(@0);
        make.height.equalTo(@100);

    }];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.text = @"Hello";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [TabBar addSubview:label];

    [label mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.top.equalTo(@0);
        make.left.equalTo(@10);
        make.right.equalTo(@-10);
        make.height.equalTo(@10);
        make.centerX.equalTo(TabBar);
    }];

    AllTrips = [self createButton:@"All"];
    AllTrips.tag = 1;
    [TabBar addSubview: AllTrips];

    OpenTrips = [self createButton:@"Open"];
    OpenTrips.tag = 2;
    [TabBar addSubview: OpenTrips];

    AssignedTrips = [self createButton:@"Assigned"];
    AssignedTrips.tag = 3;
    [TabBar addSubview: AssignedTrips];

    CompletedTrips = [self createButton:@"Completed"];
    CompletedTrips.tag = 4;
    [TabBar addSubview: CompletedTrips];


    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(AllTrips,OpenTrips,AssignedTrips,CompletedTrips);

    [TabBar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-5-[AllTrips]-2-[OpenTrips]-2-[AssignedTrips]-2-[CompletedTrips]-5-|"]
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views]];

    [TabBar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[AllTrips(==OpenTrips)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [TabBar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[OpenTrips(==AssignedTrips)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [TabBar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[AssignedTrips(==CompletedTrips)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


    NSArray * keys = @[@"AllTrips",@"OpenTrips",@"AssignedTrips",@"CompletedTrips"];

    for (NSString * key in keys) {

        [TabBar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-50-[%@(50)]",key]
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views]];
    }
}

-(UIButton *)createButton:(NSString*)Title{

    button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
     button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:Title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(ButtonAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    StripView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    StripView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    StripView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button addSubview:StripView];

    NSDictionary * StripDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(StripView);


    [button addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[StripView]-0-|"]
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:StripDic]];

    [button addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[StripView(5)]-0-|"]
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:StripDic]];
    return button;

}

-(void)ButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender{

    if(![sender isSelected]){

        [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        StripView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        sender.selected = YES;
    }
    else{

        [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        StripView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        sender.selected = NO;
    }
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: You can set HighlightedColor property of UIButton

Comment: please explain with code

Comment: please go through "Jiri Zachar" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the method like , no need of `Buttontitle` , button takes the ownership of all controls

```
button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
//set the frame for your button
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor GreenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button setTitle:Title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self
            action:@selector(ButtonAction:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

do like it is an `sender`, sender as your current button not `Buttontitle`

-(void)ButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender{

```
if(![sender isSelected]){


    for(UIView* view in sender.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] ){
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            NSLog(@"the view name ==%@",view);
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   // StripView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    sender.selected = YES;
}
else{


    for(UIView* view in sender.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] ){
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            NSLog(@"the view name ==%@",view);
        }
        else{

        }
    }
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   // StripView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sender.selected = NO;
}
}
```

Comment: @ramakrishna - chek the answer, if you need the assistance ask me

Answer (score 1):

you can define UIButton as follow code:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton new];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below in your button action method

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{
for(UIView* view in self.view.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && view != sender){
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)view;
            [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // set color whichever you want
        }
        else{
            [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // set color which ever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag value for StripView in method "createButton"

```
StripView.tag = 10;
```

Change the ButtonAction method like this

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{
    for(UIView* view in TabBar.subviews){
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)view;
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[sender viewWithTag:10] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    }
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[sender viewWithTag:10] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no XCode now, so I type codes by imaging.

```
NSArray *buttonCollection; ///< IBOutletCollection of UIButtons

- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Make all button un-selected 
    [buttonCollection setValue:@(NO) forKeyPath:@"selected"];
   
    // Make the sender UIButton selected
    sender.selected = YES;
}
```

The selected UIButton text color is black, and when they are un-selected, their text color is white. You can set `UIButton` state by [Jiri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33671446/419348)

---

#### Update

It seems like the selected `UIButton` has a custom underline. I will prefer to subclass `UIButton`, and change it's UI behavior when it is selected.